# Vim: mapping to switch window and fill screen

Tags: vim, window, keymapping

I have in my .vimrc the following lines, which lets me switch windows with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>:

```
nnoremap <C-h> <C-W>h
nnoremap <C-j> <C-W>j
nnoremap <C-k> <C-W>k
nnoremap <C-l> <C-W>l
```

These are fine for my desktop computer, but on my netbook, I want to have the active window completely fill the tiny screen. This means typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>_</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>|</kbd> after each window change. The logical step would be to add those keystrokes to the mapping, yielding:

```
nnoremap <C-h> <C-W>h<C-W>_<C-W>|
nnoremap <C-j> <C-W>j<C-W>_<C-W>|
nnoremap <C-k> <C-W>k<C-W>_<C-W>|
nnoremap <C-l> <C-W>l<C-W>_<C-W>|
```

But that fails, consistently, when in a mapping, despite working when I simply type the required keys; and (as I have set 'showcmd') it seems to leave a trailing `<C-W>`.

I have also tried using :wincmd:

```
nnoremap <C-h> :wincmd h<cr>:wincmd _<cr>:wincmd |<cr>
nnoremap <C-j> :wincmd j<cr>:wincmd _<cr>:wincmd |<cr>
nnoremap <C-k> :wincmd k<cr>:wincmd _<cr>:wincmd |<cr>
nnoremap <C-l> :wincmd l<cr>:wincmd _<cr>:wincmd |<cr>
```

But that complains about trailing `<cr>` whenever my vimrc is sourced, so I'm not going to pursue that further without more research.

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you don't want to use windows at all in your netbook so why bother? Use buffers instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `<Bar>` instead of `|`. ie:

```
nnoremap <C-h> <C-W>h<C-W>_<C-W><Bar>
nnoremap <C-j> <C-W>j<C-W>_<C-W><Bar>
nnoremap <C-k> <C-W>k<C-W>_<C-W><Bar>
nnoremap <C-l> <C-W>l<C-W>_<C-W><Bar>
```

Answer (score 1):

`|` are used to have multiply commands on one line and you will need to be escaped with a backslash when used literally:

```
nnoremap <C-h> <C-W>h<C-W>_<C-W>\|
nnoremap <C-j> <C-W>j<C-W>_<C-W>\|
nnoremap <C-k> <C-W>k<C-W>_<C-W>\|
nnoremap <C-l> <C-W>l<C-W>_<C-W>\|
```

On the other hand `|` can be useful:

```
nnoremap xxx :if 1 == 2 | echom "hello" | endif
```

Comment: I didn't know that about the `|`. That solves another question which would surely have come up in future.